# Is app.yaml on Google Cloud Platform publicly visible?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform

I want to deploy a web API on Google cloud and for test purposes I would just put the API key in the app.yaml file as an environment variable. Is this a security issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally problematic to persist secrets to files. Even if the `app.yaml` were inaccessible from the runtime service, you'd still face challenges that it be exposed in build logs and if you inadvertently commit `app.yaml` to e.g. github.

For "testing", you can run generally run an App Engine locally. This isn't a perfect replica of the production service but it should be sufficient for testing.

A solution for managing secrets is e.g. Google's [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs). SDKs (encouraged) and the underlying REST API (discouraged) are available.